# How i can display selected box with ajax codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to edit the selected box but not display it in the case I have edit button.

This my view on javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function edit(id) {
    $('#form-edit').remove();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: '',
      url: '<?php echo site_url("pangkat/edit")?>/' + id,
      success: function(data) {
        obj = JSON.parse(data);
        var html = '' +
          '<form id="form-edit">' +
            '<div class="form-group">' +
              '<label class="control-label labelnya"><i class="ion ion-home"></i>Golongan:</label>' +
              '<select class="persons" name="id_golongan" style="width: 100%" data-placeholder="Pilih Golongan">' +
                '<option></option>' +
                <?php foreach($golongan as $val) {
                  if ($val['ID_GOLONGAN'] == $id_golongan)
                    echo '<option value="'.$val['ID_GOLONGAN'].'" selected>'.$val['GOLONGAN'].'</option>';
                  else
                    echo '<option value="'.$val['ID_GOLONGAN'].'">'.$val['GOLONGAN'].'</option>';
                }?>
              '</select>' +
            '</div>' +
          '</form>';
      }
    });
  }
</script>`
```

This my controller:

```
public function edit($id = NULL)
{
  // $data['golongan'] = $this->M_golongan->get();
  $data = $this->M_pangkat->get($id);
  echo json_encode(array(
    'id_pangkat'    =>$data['ID_KENAIKAN_PANGKAT'],
    'id_pegawai'    =>$data['ID_PEGAWAI'],
    'id_golongan'   =>$data['ID_GOLONGAN'],
    'sk_pangkat'    =>$data['SK_PANGKAT'],
    'tgl_mulai'     =>date('d-m-Y ',strtotime($data['TGL_MULAI'])),
    'tgl_terhitung' =>date('d-m-Y ',strtotime($data['TGL_TERHITUNG']))
  ));
}
```

Comment: your requirement is not clear... explain..

Comment: i want showing data value from database with combobox

Comment: Formatted code blog, fixed english.